# Timer started in MouseDown event doesn't execute Tick function

Tags: c#, timer, mousedown

I want to build a function for holding a Button in C#. Currently it looks like this:

```
private Timer timer1 = new Timer();

private void cmd_haken_auf_ab_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("works");
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();

}

private void cmd_haken_auf_ab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("works too");
    timer1.Stop();
}


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("works as well");
    cmd_p4.Height += 1;

}
```

But appearently my `timer1_Tick` function is never executed, as the Output is:

```
works
works too
works
works too
```

Comment: What delay do you have on your timer - this doesnt show here

Comment: You never hooked up your tick event, at least from the code you provided

Comment: I actually forgot to set a timer and link the Tick function... Thanks for hinting me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

mention timer `tick_event` for your timer and add timer `interval`.

`timer1.Interval = 1000;
timer1.Tick+=timer1_Tick;`

Answer (score 0):

Add in constructor:

```
timer1.Tick += new timer1_Tick(TimerEventProcessor);
```

This should result in call every tick of your timer. If wont work, set interval of timer like

```
timer1.Interval = 1; // 1ms interval
```